# buildpack install npm during build process

Tags: spring-boot, docker, buildpack

I'm new to the `Buildpacks` area, and I want to create a Docker image for my project. My project is written in Java (with the `Spring Boot` framework), and it also includes a `Vue.js` project. I'm using Maven for building the project, and I have a `pom.xml` file in the root of the project that builds both the Java backend and the `Vue.js` frontend together, merging them into a single `.jar` file (with an embedded Tomcat) to be able to run it.

When I try to build my project using the following command, it gives me an error:

```
$ pack build myapp --builder paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base
...
[builder]   Compiled Application: Contributing to layer
[builder]     Executing mvn --batch-mode -Dmaven.test.skip=true --no-transfer-progress package
[builder]       [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[builder]       [INFO]
[builder]       [INFO] -----------------< web >-----------------
[builder]       [INFO] Building nsp-step-web 4.20.2
[builder]       [INFO]   from pom.xml
[builder]       [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[builder]       [INFO]
[builder]       [INFO] --- exec:3.1.0:exec (exec-npm-install) @ nsp-step-web ---
[builder]       [ERROR] Command execution failed.
[builder]       java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "npm" (in directory "/workspace/src/main/front_vue"): error=2, No such file or directory
[builder]           at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start (ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
[builder]           at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExtendedExecutor.launch (ExtendedExecutor.java:71)
[builder]           at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:336)
[builder]           at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
[builder]           at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:1000)
[builder]           at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:947)
[builder]           at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:471)
```

It seems that it couldn't find `npm` during the build phase.

My project structure is like this:

```
.
├── pom.xml
├── project.toml
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── front_vue
│   │   │   ├── babel.config.js
│   │   │   ├── jsconfig.json
│   │   │   ├── node_modules
│   │   │   ├── package.json
│   │   │   ├── src
│   │   │   └── vue.config.js
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── com
│   │   └── resources
│   │       ├── application.properties
```

and here's my `project.toml` file:

```
[[build.env]]
name = "BP_JVM_VERSION"
value = "8"

[[build.env]]
name = "BP_NODE_VERSION"
value = "16.20.0"

[[build.env]]
name = "BP_NPM_VERSION"
value = "8"

[[build.env]]
name = "BP_INSTALL_NODE"
value = "true"

[[build.env]]
name = "BP_INSTALL_NPM"
value = "true"
```

How can I instruct the buildpack to install `npm` in a similar way to installing Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove these from your `project.toml`.

```
[[build.env]]
name = "BP_NPM_VERSION"
value = "8"

[[build.env]]
name = "BP_INSTALL_NODE"
value = "true"

[[build.env]]
name = "BP_INSTALL_NPM"
value = "true"
```

They do not correspond to any actual settings.

2. Add this one.

```
[[build.env]]
name = "BP_JAVA_INSTALL_NODE"
value = "true"
```

This will tell the Java buildpacks that you need to build both your Java & Node projects. It should trigger all of the required resources to be installed, i.e. a JDK & Node + NPM.

3. Re-run your build.

That should be it.

You can also check out the example project for this type of build here: https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/samples/tree/main/java/java-node/maven-yarn

If that doesn't work for some reason, please update with the full build output.

Comment: Thanks for your approach; it resolved my error. But now, I have another problem. When I run the `npm run build`, which is equal to the `vue-cli-service build --modern` command inside my local machine, it works well. However, when it's running inside the pack build container, it gives the `sh: 1: vue-cli-service: not found` error. The `npm install` command is running before the `npm run build` inside the `pom.xml` file, but it seems that the `node_modules/.bin/` directory did not automatically get added to `$PATH`

Comment: Try changing your command to `npx vue-cli-service build --modern`. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npx I think that should take care of path issues when calling things installed by NPM & `npx` should be on the PATH. The buildpack install of Node.js should do that.

Comment: thanks for your attention. the problem was the in the `devDependencies` section of my `package.json` file and the buildpack was setting the `NODE_ENV=production` automatically so the vue-cli-service did not installed during `npm install` command and cause the  `vue-cli-service: not found` error